# Is it possible to block, filter, or minimize Facebook chat "stickers"?

Tags: facebook, chat

Facebook has recently made great strides in their effort to be the most evil web app of all time, by adding "stickers" to chat.

[image: Example of annoying stickers]

The most annoying thing about these "stickers", is that they are so huge.  They take up at least 75% of the default chat window, often requiring me to scroll up to read a previous sentence.

If they were just the size of a normal emoticon, I wouldn't mind.  Is there a way (possibly by way of a third-party add-on/browser extension?) to reduce the size of these stickers, or even completely filter them?

My attempts to google a solution only offer suggestions on how to use stickers.  *sigh*

Comment: Get better friends (the kind who won't use them!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom scripts to control the appearance of the stickers. For that you need to use a plugin on your browser that can do that, [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for FireFox) and [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) (for Chrome)

Once you install the extension/plugin, you are ready to add the script for any site. I am not sure about Greasemonkey's function, to add a new script to Facebook, click on the Tampermonkey icon that might appear after you add the extension and click on "Add New Script" and simply paste this below all the code in the textarea:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.addRule(".stickerContainer div", "background-size: 20px 20px !important; height: 20px !important;width: 20px !important;", 1);
```

[image: Code Entered]

**And the result:**

[image: Sticker Downsized on Facebook]

The above code will downsize the stickers. If you want to completely hide it (which I don't recommend) use the following code:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
sheet.addRule(".stickerContainer div", "display:none;", 1);
```

Please see the documentation of the plugin/extension before you use.

Comment: I'm finally getting around to trying this, and it's sadly not working for me.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome/Firefox, AdBlock is the way to go. Add a filter like this:

```
||fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net^
```

Comment: Won't that block more than just Facebook chat stickers?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the stickers are images with the classes "img mvs". So you could write a user script that autohides all images with the mvs class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/features.htm)

> Hide Smileys / Emoticons
>
> If you don't like the graphical smileys aka emoticons and "stickers" that Facebook displays, you can hide them with FBP's built in Emoticon hiding option

Comment: In spite of that, in my opinion, when people give you a sticker, it means that they want to express an emotion. Even when you understand what they want to share by the words they say, it still be better to feel them by emoticons (or stickers).

Comment: Visit [Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/features.html) to have an other Facebook customizing tool (aka make-it-better tool).